# Solve the integral $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\int_{y=0}^{x}\frac{\cos{(x-y)}-\cos{x}}{y}dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Find the value of:

$$I=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\int_{y=0}^{x}\dfrac{\cos{(x-y)}-\cos{x}}{y}dy \ dx$$

I think we could take:
$$I=\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y}\int_{x=y}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{(x-y)}-\cos{x}}{x}dx\ dy$$

Answer (score 6):

Don't answer this question until September 30 , 2013 
it is a problem 17709 in American Mathematical Monthly May 2013.

Comment: did you consider flagging the question?

Comment: This must be an incorrect problem number.

Comment: @Stefan: Unregistered users; as well as registered users with reputation below 15 points cannot use the flag system.

Comment: @copper.hat : I don't belong to MAA anymore. Does the problem appear in the Monthly?

Comment: @StefanSmith: I have the April edition, the problem range is 11698-11704, so the above number doesn’t jive. (Possibly it should be 11709?)